# Scala Slick. How to change a column value using Case

Tags: scala, slick

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)

def changeNameQuery(): Query[UserTable, User, Seq] = {
  TableQuery[UserTable].map { user => 
    (Case If (user.name === "A") Then "B" Else "A",
     user.age
    )
  }
}
```

i get this error

```
[error]  found   : slick.lifted.Query[(slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Int]),(String, Int),Seq]
[error]  required: repositories.postgres.PostgresProfile.api.Query[repositories.postgres.UserTable,model.User,Seq]
```

Maybe there is some way to get a table object back from a tuple?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight it seems a typing problem. You are saying that you will return a `Query[User Table, User, Seq]`, which means from the user table you are going to return a list of users. The error says that you are returning a tuple `(String,Int)` instead of `User`.

Instead of doing

```scala
(
  Case If (user.name === "A") Then "B" Else "A",
  user.age   
)
```

You need to return a `User` or change the return type of your method. It depends on what you need

Comment: yes, you are right i need User but user name should be changed, and it should be Query bcz its part of big Query so is there some way to change name of user inside Query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `slick.jdbc.Database.run` method?

```scala
val db: Database = Database.forConfig("myDatabase")
db.run(analyticsActivityTableQuery += value)
```

You can check and update the value of value.

Comment: it should be Query bcz its part of big Query